# How can Console2 use the current directory as the name of a bash tab?

Tags: bash, tabs, console, console2, title

Is this possible at all? (basically a pendant to cmd.exe's `title` command that Mikel's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/235621/how-can-console2-use-the-current-directory-as-the-name-of-a-bash-tab/235628#235628) mentions, although I'd prefer changing the entire tab name instead of adding a window title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bash`, the standard Xterm sequences documented at [How to change the title of an xterm](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html) seem to work, e.g.

```
echo -e "\033]0;custom title\007"; cat
```

So try adding that to your `PS1` in your `.bashrc` or whichever config file you use, e.g:

```
PS1="\033]0;\$PWD\007$PS1"
```

or use `PROMPT_COMMAND` instead if you are using `bash`.

---

In `cmd.exe`, you can use `title <string>` to set the title.

You would chain it together using a [doskey](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection126121120120) alias like this:

```
doskey cd=title $1 ^&^& cd $1
```

Then set it to load for every new `cmd` using the instructions in 
[Loading DOSKEY Automatically with CMD](http://www.tildemark.com/at-work/loading-doskey-automatically-with-cmd.html).

---

In both cases, to show only the window title, go to  `Settings->Appearance` and tick the
`Use console window title*` box.

Comment: I'm afraid `title` is a built-in of cmd.exe, so bash claims `bash: title: command not found` :( but it works for cmd.exe, so +1

Comment: thanks for the update - wow, doskey's still around? Hm, I'd probably first of all `doskey alias=doske`

Comment: Yes, my original answer was only for `cmd`.  I have updated it with instructions for `bash`.

Comment: your current solution won't change the working directory, using `PS1='\033]0;\u@\h:\w\007'$PS1` instead does the trick

Comment: Sorry, yes, there was a missing backslash.  It is fixed now.

Comment: @Tobias: fwiw, these days `doskey` is just a thin wrapper around Console API.

Answer (score 1):

Been a while, but the only post that mostly answered my problem
Building on the answer from Mikel and the comment from Tobias, adding

`PS1='\[\033]2;\u:\w\007\]'$PS1`

to `~/.bashrc` allowed [consoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) (successor to console2) to show the shell title in the consoleZ tab, and not mess up line wrapping in the shell.

"Note the use of `\[...\]`, which tells bash to ignore the non-printing control characters when calculating the width of the prompt. Otherwise line editing commands get confused while placing the cursor."
http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html#ss4.3